# fail (backjumping, conflict set: cardano-crypto-class)

Tags: cabal, cardano

I am trying to install `cardano-node` to my MacOS by [this](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#building-and-installing-the-node-1) article.

After `cabal build all` command I got:

```
➜  cardano-node git:(4c5944295) cabal build all
Warning: Requested index-state 2021-04-30T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2021-04-29T23:07:55Z).
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: cardano-crypto-class (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0 (conflict: pkg-config package
libsodium-any, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: cardano-crypto-class)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: cardano-crypto-class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the important part:

```
conflict: pkg-config package libsodium-any, not found in the pkg-config database
```

You need to install `libsodium`.

I think the `cabal configure --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.4` step should have failed with the same error. Maybe you missed it: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#configuring-the-build-options. And maybe you also need to retry the "downloading & compiling" steps: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#downloading--compiling.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with libsodium

Comment: Sadly, 2 years later, linstalling `libsodium` no longer helps and the problem is back.